# pre_replace php Function

Tags: php, string

A simple question:

I have a string with this value:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:62:"https://www.google.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/0.jpg";}
```

and would like to remove the special characters in the beginning (a:1:{i:0;s:62:") and at the end (";}) of the string but i can only remove the beginning pattern using the following function:

```
function RemoveSpecialChar($value){
$result  = preg_replace('/a:1:{i:0;s:62:"/','',$value);
return $result;
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: it's a serialize data. use `unserialize()` to get actual data

Comment: currently it is giving me this in the code state at the moment:  https://www.google.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/0.jpg";}

Comment: Thanks @AnantKumarSingh i will give it a try

Comment: @shakel  from where you got this data?You itself created it?

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh Im pulling data from an xml feed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rtrim($variable,"thin that wanted to delete")` function. This will help you to delete from right side. For left side use `ltrim()`.

Here is my code:

```
$str = "a:1:{i:0;s:62:'https://www.google.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/0.jpg';}";
   
$str2 = rtrim($str,";}");

echo $str2; //will delete the right part
```